# Some Font Awesome Icons Don't Appear in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I'm having a weird issue with some, but not all, font awesome icons.

I know it's not an issue with the installation of the gem, because when I use some icons it works perfectly.  For example, this displays the desired house without a hitch:

```
  <%= fa_icon "home", class: "color-house" %>
```

However, other icons (these four) simply don't appear:

```
  <%= fa_icon "ring", class: "color-spouse" %>
  <%= fa_icon "baby", class: "color-kids" %>
  <%= fa_icon "spa", class: "color-self" %>
  <%= fa_icon "pen-fancy", class: "color-self" %>
```

I'm using [this site](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=pen&m=free) to search for the icon names.

I recently ran `bundle update` and am have `font-awesome-rails (4.7.0.4)` in my `Gemfile.lock`.

I have also tried using a CDN for font awesome with this file in my `<head>`, but to no avail:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Is this just a Font Awesome version issue? If you go to the [4.7.0 search page](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/?d=gallery), you'll find "home" but not "pen-fancy".

Comment: @muistooshort Yes.  I had to install a new gem (font awesome 5).  Thanks!